# Have vs. Had Special Situation

Tags: grammar

This is part of my essay that I'm writing, and I'm unsure of whether to use "has" or "have."

"that experience, and others like it, have/has taught me"

That experience has taught me, but others like it have taught me.  Which one should be used in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

"That experience, and others like it, have taught me" is correct, because the subject (that experience, and others like it) is plural.

Answer (score 0):

The correct term is *have*, but you can avoid confusion altogether by leaving it out:

> "that experience, and others like it, taught me"